# How does Solr's /sql request handler work without the collection holding any data?

Tags: solr

I'm going through Solr's documentation for the [parallel SQL interface](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/parallel-sql-interface.html). In the [best practices](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/parallel-sql-interface.html#best-practices) section, I see the following:

> It makes sense to create a separate SolrCloud collection just for the
> /sql handler. This collection can be created using SolrCloud’s
> standard collection API. Since this collection only exists to handle
> /sql requests and provide a pool of worker nodes, this collection does
> not need to hold any data.

I don't understand how having a separate collection, and that too, without data, will help. I would imagine that having the collection where the data resides and configuring a `/sql` handler in that collection is the way to go because the Solr boxes themselves would be the pool of worker nodes. How does having a new collection just to handle `/sql` requests exactly help here? And how does it function without having the data? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows you to grow the available number of workers without having to replicate your data to even more nodes without gaining anything in regards to performance in the SQL interface. This allows you to introduce pure worker nodes, and scale your requirements for SQL handling without having to scale your data for all collections involved.

The SQL interface is common across *all collections*, since a collection is represented by the table name in the SQL query. The workers then contact one of the replicas for each shard int he collection in the background, merge the result and provide it back. Since this is independent of the collection itself, there is no need to use the workers that are attached to a specific collection.

The Data Table illustration shown in the manual (further down than the quote you're referencing) shows how this works:

[image: Graph showing how each worker node contacts each collection to retrieve their results]

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh. So, if I understand correctly, you're saying I will have 2 collections - one that has my business data and one that has no data with the implicit `/sql` handler, right? If I'm using JDBC to connect, I will have to connect to the 2nd collection. Since, I will specify which collection to exactly query to, there's no ambiguity on which collection the WHERE clauses will be executed. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The data will be from the collection given in the `FROM` part of your SQL collection. You'll connect to the "meta"-collection containing your sql handler.

Comment: Got it. One last question - if I introduce more shards and use them as the workers too, I will effectively parallelise my search space while also allowing for data locality and more processing computes. Would you say it's a decent strategy to start with and do some perf test on this configuration?

Comment: Yes, that's what part of the best practice refers to - it allows you to move the processing of results sets out from handling the querying itself. Whether it's necessary will depend on your use case, but if it's something you foresee already now, it'd be worth experimenting with.